# How do I paginate in django?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Here is the code of the views.py

```
def view_images(request):
    return render_to_response('gallery/index.html',{
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'images': Image.objects.all(),
        'video': Video.objects.all()
    })
```

I know its a messy way to code but I want to paginate this code

Comment: Have you read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view? The example in the docs is using only one model, in your case you would have to handle the corner cases, that may arise here.

Comment: I have read the docs but the problem arises I have 3 querysets as you can see and I dont know how to paginate them together

Comment: might help you.. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10575/

Comment: You should rephrase your question to reflect your specific requirement. Good Q and A is also helpful for others. ;)

Comment: As @allcaps mentioned, you need to specify what you need. You could obviously create 3 `Paginator`s, set the page sizes and return the corresponding page for each one of them and then handle cases when (for example) `Category` doesn't have the next page but `Image` and `Video` do, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.11 It’s possible to combine queries across different tables using the [SQL union operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union).

```
>>> qs1 = Author.objects.values_list('name')
>>> qs2 = Entry.objects.values_list('headline')
>>> qs1.union(qs2).order_by('name')
```

Now jou can feed `qs1` into a [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator).

[The documentations shows how to implement this in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view). I'm not going to copy paste examples. Just read the documentation on pagination.